# How to disable automatic browser cookie login with Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using B2C custom policies.

I am using `Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider` documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile

The signin relying party of the custom policy is working well, except users won't get user/password challenge after a successful login. I guess the technical profile uses browser cookies like "`x-ms-cpim-cache|o4wex_p_gejeeak6w_0`" for domain `b2clogin.com` to remember a successful login for at least a browser session.

The Metadata "`setting.enableRememberMe`" is the default that is set to false.

I need to make sure users are challenged with user/pwd every tinme the signin relying party is called. Is there any way to disable the auto-login with the cookie cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the session management technical profile to SM-Noop on the sign in technical profile.

For JavaScript apps, this will break silent token calls for an access token.

Other option, for initial logins, send the query param prompt=login which will kill the cookies when the user arrives at B2C. This at least keeps silent token calls working for JS apps.